# How Airflow connects to Spark and Is it possible to set a different access right to users in Airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Hi I am still new to Airflow.  I would like to know how Airflow connects to Spark?
I have a server that is with different accounts (or profiles) to access the Spark cluster. I wonder Does Airflow have a fixed profile to connect the spark? or It follows the user profile?

Also, Is it possible to set a different access right to users in Airflow? 
For example, User A that has right to access location A in Spark (or hdfs) can only run task that is related to location A. (so It is not possible to run any job from location B)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the community contributed SparkSubmitOperator in the conrtib folder of Airflow repo. Basically, this operator runs a spark-submit subprocess through python and waits for its completion. This operator has been significantly improved since the previous stable release (1.8.1). This works quite well if you already have spark setup and do not want airflow to control where the spark jobs run.

The user rights issue is more complex. One of the ways, you might be able to fix it is by modifying the SparkSubmitOperator to set environment parameters for the subprocess, and take this parameter as (an extra) input to this operator.